# Spring MVC submit input form id's and values to form backing object

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring MVC to automatically map the values of my input fields to a form backing object on submit. I want the values of most input fields, however there are some fields where I want the input id element. For example, If the user selects "English" as a language, I don't want the value of the form backing object to be "English", I want it instead to be "en" (which is set as the input id upon language selection).

What is a typical way of handling this situation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is [select tag](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-jsp-formtaglib-selecttag). Typical usage:

```
<form:select id="language" path="language" items="${availableLanguages}" />
```

And somewhere in your controller:

```
modelAndView.addObject("availableLanguages", new HashMap<String, String>(){
    {
        put("en", "English");
        put("ru", "Russian");
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi madhead, unfortunately I am working with a regular input field (text box), and not a selection box. I have a requirement that users should select languages via an autocomplete field, which I am using jQuery for. Is there a potential solution for a regular input field?

Comment: 1) `<form:input />` it renders absolutely standart HTML input; 2) `<input name="model.field">` if you cannot use spring tags. But if you use Spring Data Binding nothing stops you from using Spring TLDs. What's the problem with inputs?